# How to sum the result of list.count()

Tags: python, python-3.x, count

I am trying to summarize the number of vowels in a string. How do I total the result of my count?

```py
def count_vowels(string):
    vowel = 'aeiou'
    for i in list(vowel):
        if i in list(string):
                print(string.count(i))

count_vowels('abcod') # 2
count_vowels('coliioor') # 5
count_vowels('colour') #3
```

Current output:

```
1 first word
1 first word
2 second word
3 second word
2 third word
1 third word
```

Comment: As it stands, you can't, because you're only *printing* it.

Comment: I had to edit it the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sum()` function:

```
def count_vowels(s):
    return sum(ch in 'aeiou' for ch in s)

print(count_vowels('abcod')) # 2
print(count_vowels('coliioor')) # 5
print(count_vowels('colour')) #3
```

Prints:

```
2
5
3
```

Comment: Hi Andrej, could you please take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping) to offer any solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, you're not returning anything from the function, and, your function should use a variable to store the sum and keep increasing it as the loop executes (and you don't need to convert a string to a list to iterate over it, strings are iterable too):

```
def count_vowels(string):
    vowel = 'aeiou'
    result = 0
    for i in vowel:
        if i in string:
            result += string.count(i)
    return result
```

A better approach, however, would be to invert your loops:

```
def count_vowels(string):
    vowel = 'aeiou'
    result = 0
    for i in string:
        if i in vowel:
            result += 1
    return result
```

Comment: The `if i in string` check is redundant and in the worst case doubles the running time. (Okay, fixed with the better approach) Even better (at least shorter): `return sum(1 for c in string if c in "aeiou")`

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful.  So from what I understand, I should not try to sum string.count(i).

Comment: @Zoh It's just that your previous code has a complexity of `O(N^2)`, while the second one is `O(N)` (because `count` loops over the entire string, even though the outer loop already loops over it).

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you (I've commented new lines that are not in your code):

```
def count_vowels(string):
    sum_of_vowels = 0 # new line
    vowel = 'aeiou'
    for i in list(vowel):
        if i in list(string):
            sum_of_vowels += string.count(i) # new line
    return sum_of_vowels 


print(count_vowels('abcod'))
print(count_vowels('coliioor'))
print(count_vowels('colour'))
```

out:

```
2
5
3
```

**BETTER WAY:**

just do this like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15489612/counting-occurrences-of-multiple-strings-in-another-string):

```
def count_vowels(s):
    return sum(vo in 'aeiou' for vo in s)
```